# In AWS, Why would SNS send the SNSMessage to my Email, and Trigger a Lamdba, but Not Send the Message Contents to the Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have a Lambda written in C# uploaded as a Docker container.

The Lambda is triggered by an SNS topic.

In SNS, there are 2 subscriptions to that topic, the first is my email, and the second is the Lambda.

When I trigger the topic with an event message, I get an email that contains event JSON and the Lambda is triggered.

For some reason I have not been able to identify, when the Lambda prints out the contents of the Amazon provided `Amazon.Lambda.SNSEvents.SNSEvent.SNSMessage` object to the console, I get a collection of null or empty strings. This later causes an exception in my code when I try to deserialize the Message contents from the event.

The email I receive from SNS however contains a well formed JSON object containing the full SNS object.

If I copy the contents of this email into the "Test" tab on my Lambda's UI page, the Lambda runs correctly and produces no errors.

I thought an SNS trigger for a Lambda would automatically pass the contents of the triggering message through to the Lambda function, but this doesn't seem to be the case. Does anyone know why, and how to fix my issue?

**EDIT**
For good measure, here is the entire entry point class for my Lambda. The Lambda entry point is defined as the MySNSEventHandler() method in the DockerFile.

```cs
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using Amazon.Lambda.SNSEvents;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using MySNSEventListener.EventHandlers;
using MySNSEventListener.Interfaces;

// Assembly attribute to enable the Lambda function's JSON input to be converted into a .NET class.
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson.DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer))]

namespace MySNSEventListener;

public class MySNSEventHandler
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This function is the entry point for the Lambda. It creates a new MySNSEventFactory and passes it to another method where the actual functionality lives.
    /// These are separated out so that the functionality is testable by the Moq framework, as we need to be able to pass something in if we want to mock it within the tested function.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="incomingMessage"></param>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task MySNSEventHandler(SNSEvent.SNSMessage incomingMessage, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        IMySNSEventFactory eventFactory = new MySNSEventFactory();
        await MySNSEventHandlerWithFactory(eventFactory, incomingMessage, context);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Uses the passed in MySNSEventFactory to create an MySNSEvent and then make that event execute its own functionality.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="MySNSEventFactory"></param>
    /// <param name="incomingMessage"></param>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    public async Task MySNSEventHandlerWithFactory(IMySNSEventFactory MySNSEventFactory, SNSEvent.SNSMessage incomingMessage, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        if (incomingMessage != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Incoming SNS Message:");
            Console.WriteLine($"\tType:             {incomingMessage.Type}");
            Console.WriteLine($"\tMessageId:        {incomingMessage.MessageId}");
            Console.WriteLine($"\tTopicArn:         {incomingMessage.TopicArn}");
            Console.WriteLine($"\tMessage:          {incomingMessage.Message}");
            Console.WriteLine($"\tTimeStamp:        {incomingMessage.Timestamp}");
            Console.WriteLine($"\tSignatureVersion: {incomingMessage.SignatureVersion}");
            Console.WriteLine($"\tSignature:        {incomingMessage.Signature}");
            Console.WriteLine($"\tUnsubscribeUrl:   {incomingMessage.UnsubscribeUrl}");


            IMySNSEventHandler MySNSEvent = MySNSEventFactory.GetMySNSEvent(_lambdaHttpClientManager, incomingMessage);
            await MySNSEvent.PerformEventActionAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Incoming message was null.");
        }
    }

    /// From this line until the end of this class, this code was written to enable proper mocking and dependency injection.
    private static IServiceProvider _services = default!;
    private static ILambdaHttpClientManager _lambdaHttpClientManager = default!;

    public MySNSEventHandler()
    {
        ConfigureServices();
    }

    public MySNSEventHandler(ILambdaHttpClientManager lambdaHttpClientManager)
    {
        _lambdaHttpClientManager = lambdaHttpClientManager;
    }

    private void ConfigureServices()
    {
        var _host = LambdaHostManager.GetLambdaHostManager().CreateHostBuilder();
        
        _services = _host.Build().Services;
        _lambdaHttpClientManager = new LambdaHttpClientManager(_services.GetService<IHttpClientFactory>())!;
    }
    // This ends the code to enable dependency injection.
}
```

Which outputs

```
Incoming SNS Message:
    Type:
    MessageId:
    TopicArn:
    Message:
    TimeStamp: 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
    SignatureVersion:
    Signature:
    UnsubscribeUrl:
```

When the Lambda is triggered by SNS.

Comment: What does the event look like in the lambda?

Comment: I added some extra info to the Question, but long story short, the event looks empty. I don't know how to see the raw text of the event as it was used to invoke the Lambda either.

Comment: The given code is not enough to identify the problem, so add more code to understand on how you read the SNS message value from SNSEvents.

Comment: I went ahead and added the entire entry point class for the lambda. Do I need to add any code from the Dockerfile?

Comment: I went ahead and added the entire entry point class for the lambda. Do I need to add any code from the Dockerfile?